# An interface giving me java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, linux

My program compiled fine. But the problems start when I try to run it.

```
jesvin@Jesvin-Technovia:~/dev/drools/sudoku$ java App 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/drools/planner/core/solution/Solution
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.planner.core.solution.Solution
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: App. Program will exit.
```

I know that the interface `Solution` was correctly resolved in compile time.

Here is the offending class `Sudoku` that `implements Solution`:

```
package domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.drools.planner.api.domain.solution.PlanningEntityCollectionProperty;
import org.drools.planner.core.solution.Solution;
import org.drools.planner.core.score.SimpleScore;

public class Sudoku implements Solution<SimpleScore>{
...
```

And here is the `App` class that is supposed to use an instance of the `Sudoku` class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
...

import org.drools.planner.config.XmlSolverConfigurer;
...

//solution too
import org.drools.planner.core.solution.Solution;

import solution.SudokuGenerator;
import domain.Sudoku;

public class App{
    public static void main(String[] args){
    SudokuGenerator sg = new SudokuGenerator();
    Solution sudoku = sg.createSudoku();
    Solver solver = createSolver();
    solver.setPlanningProblem(sudoku);
    solver.solve();

    Sudoku result = (Sudoku) solver.getBestSolution();
    result.displaySolution();
    }

    private static Solver createSolver(){
    XmlSolverConfigurer configurer = new XmlSolverConfigurer();
        configurer.configure("solver.xml");
        return configurer.buildSolver();
    }
}
```

Is it the result of me wrongly casting between `Sudoku` and `Solution`?

---

My classpath is set as:

```
declare -x CLASSPATH=".:/home/jesvin/dev/drools/sudoku/binaries"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @GPRathour wrote above, you need to add the **jars** from drools planner to the classpath.

I guess `/home/jesvin/dev/drools/sudoku/binaries` is a directory. You need put jars there.
Some thing like...

`declare -x CLASSPATH=".:/home/jesvin/dev/drools/sudoku/binaries/drools-planner-core.jar`

A better approach will be to add jars in the command line via -classpath

`java -classpath path/jar1;path/jar App`

In a  exception stack you should always check the 'caused by ' messages. In this your real exception was  `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.planner.core.solution.Solution`.

( Other thing to note--   Use packages. Having classes in appropriate packages helps lot in reading code later.)

Comment: Right on! I used the `dir/*` feature to import all the jars as in `declare -x CLASSPATH=".:/home/jesvin/dev/drools/sudoku/binaries/*"`. The compiler's class path was hardcoded into a custom command and I carelessly left the environment variable wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add external Jar file of class `org.drools.planner.core.solution.Solution`.

You can get it [from here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/d/Downloaddroolsplannercore520Finaljar.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a built tool which can take care of third party dependencies. For an example you can simple use maven as the build tool and inside the project pom file you can declare all the dependencies which you need.Following is a example for junit dependency.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.0</version>
  <type>jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```